# Changing an image from third party server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to change an image on a script I don't have access to (hosted on a 3rd party server).

The image I want to display is in a href but the img src shows a thumbnail version.

I'm presuming I need some sort of jQuery script that replaces each instance (there could be more than one) with the appended version.

The div is:

```
<div id="imagezoomcontainer">
<a target="_blank" class="chatlink" href="goodimage.jpg">
<span></span>
<img src="badimage.jpg" align="middle" border="0" height="100" width="100"></a>
</div>
```

I wish I just had access to the server - would save a lot of time!

Comment: so `badimage.jpg` should be replaced with what `badimageBig.jpg`?

Comment: No, badimage.jpg should be replaced with goodimage.jpg

Answer (score 2):

this is a basic example, that will make that change on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#imagezoomcontainer img").attr("src",$("#imagezoomcontainer .chatlink").attr("href"));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - Can this work for multiple images with the same id? It's on a dynamic page (a live chat system) so I've had to create it as a button for now - how would you run it? I was thinking maybe a check every 10 seconds?

Comment: This only works for one image, since it makes the `src` the same for all the images it goes through

Answer (score 1):

As you've guessed you'll need to go through all images and make the change. You can use an `$.each` loop for that like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.each("#imagezoomcontainer img", function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).parent().children(".chatlink").attr("href");
   });
});
```

Comment: yup, put it in a `setInterval(...function here..., x000)` - where x is substituted with the number of seconds

Comment: yup, in the `$(document).ready` because you need it to make sure your pictures are loaded into the DOM already

Comment: The problem is the images are loaded after the .ready It's a live chat system so the images could appear at anytime

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".chatlink").click(function(){
  e.preventDefault();
  var thisObj = $(this);
  thisObj.next("img").attr("src", thisObj.attr("href"));
});
```